# imaplib copy Email to Folder (subfolder) on live.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib, outlook.com

I am trying to copy mails from Inbox to a subfolder on live.com. Due limitations of the system, I only can work with the default libraries of python 3.8.
The code to list the directories of the account looks like this:

```
imapcon = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
imapcon.login(imap_user, imap_pass)
for i in imapcon.list()[1]:
    print(i)
```

The result is:

```
b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Archive'
b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Trash) "/" Deleted'
b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Drafts) "/" Drafts'
b'(\\Marked \\HasChildren) "/" Inbox'
b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Inbox/check'
b'(\\Marked \\HasNoChildren) "/" Inbox/stuf'
b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Inbox/test1in'
b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Inbox/test1st'
b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Junk) "/" Junk'
b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Notes'
b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Outbox'
b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" rootstuff'
b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Sent) "/" Sent'
```

My code to copy looks like this:

```
resp, items = imapcon.uid("search",None, 'All')
items = items[0].split()
for emailid in items:
    cpres = imapcon.uid('COPY',emailid, 'Inbox/test1in')
    print(cpres)
```

Unfortunately, the mail will not be copied. I found mostly Gmail folder specific hints, but nothing worked out. Tried `cpres = imapcon.uid('COPY',emailid, '/test1in')` or `cpres = imapcon.uid('COPY',emailid, '\Inbox.test1in')`
I found examples with brackets.... so I tried `cpres = imapcon.uid('COPY',emailid, '(\Inbox/test1in)')`

To make life easier, I tried to copy the folder rootstuff `cpres = imapcon.uid('COPY',emailid, 'rootstuff')` and this works fine. To the Inbox/Subfolders not. Where is my mistake?

EDIT:

the print for `cpres = imapcon.uid('COPY',emailid, 'Inbox/test1in')`  is

```
('NO', [b'[TRYCREATE] The destination mailbox could not be found.'])
```

and for `cpres = imapcon.uid('COPY',emailid, 'rootstuff')` the script prints

```
('OK', [None])
```

I am not sure but I doubt it is something with subfolders.

Comment: What is the result of of UID COPY?  You print it but didn't tell us what it is.  Did you select a mailbox before doing search?

Comment: Good point I forgot this. I’ll add them later today

Comment: try my lib https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Comment: @Max, sorry for the delay, I edited the question.

Comment: @Vladimir, sorry besides the default packages I am not allowed to use others. I have seen your effords to promote your lib in different questions and I dont doubt it's useful - but not possible to use in this scenario